# Print a table with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am a starter with programming in LINQ and I would like to know how I can print all the data from a table (in SQL Server) using LINQ from a console application. What I have done till now is to create a table called Response which has several fields (I have designed the table in SQL Server Management Studio) and have written a console C# class to print all the values out. Here's my code for that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LinqConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (DatabaseDBDataContext responses = new DatabaseDBDataContext()) 
            {
                IEnumerable<Response> responses = from response in responses.Responses select response; 

                foreach (Response response in responses)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run this in cmd, I get this as my output:

LinqConsoleApplication.Response

LinqConsoleApplication.Response

From googling for some solutions, I have found that `Console.WriteLine(response)` should return EVERYTHING (select *) from a table, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Any suggestions please? Is there an error in the way I have framed the query? Will I need to use a StringBuilder method to append each and every field to the `writeLine()`?

Comment: Console.WriteLine(response.Name); maybe?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(response)` is printing `response.ToString()`, which is the type name of `Response`. I think you need to print a *property* of your `response` object.

Comment: @rene, that would return only the name value, but I want all the fields' values printed out. Any suggestions?

Comment: retailcoder, thank you for you answer, can you please explain your solution a bit more?

Comment: Try [JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response)](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with using reflection.Make sure you're using 
System.Reflection.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (AcumenProjectsDBDataContext acumenResponse = new AcumenProjectsDBDataContext()) 
  {
    IEnumerable<Response> responseData = from response in acumenResponse.Responses select response; 
    //added code
     foreach (Response response in responseData)
     {
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in response.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
          object value = prop.GetValue(response, new object[] { });
          Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", prop.Name, value);
        }
      }
      Console.ReadKey();
   }

}
```

Comment: I'd do that in the type's ToString override, otherwise it's single-use.

Comment: This answer does get the desired output, but like retailcoder said, it might be a bit of an overkill. Thanks a lot everyone for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the type of the "response" variable in your foreach loop. It's `LinqConsoleApplication.Response`. When an object is passed to the `Console.WriteLine(object)` method the `ToString()` method is called of that object. When you call the `ToString()` method of an object without explicitly overriding it and implementing a custom functionallity, then the default result is that you get the full object type as a string e.g. `"LinqConsoleApplication.Response"`.

What you need to do is while iterating in the foreach loop to create a custom string which is created by a concatenation of the properties of the object in which you're interested in.

For example:

```
foreach (Response response in responseData)
            {
                string responseString = response.SomeProperty1.ToString() + " " + response.SomeProperty2.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            }
```

Comment: You might want to edit your answer to actually *use* the string you're building. Otherwise the output remains unchanged...

Comment: That's what I have done for now, but what can I do when a table contains over 15 fields? Would have I have explicitly convert each field toString() and print them? That would be a lot code writing, right? Is there no DataTable concept in LINQ which can return all the data (for all the fields) from a table?

Comment: This way involves a single-use string, you'd have to retype everything (or copy/paste) every time you need to render your type as a string.

Answer (score 0):

We can't give you a definitive answer until we know what `Response` is made of and what you'd like to print out of it, but if you want to keep your `Console.WriteLine` call exactly as it is, you should override the `ToString()` method in your `Response` class, to return the string you'd like to see printed.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Property1: {0}\nProperty2: {1}\nProperty3: {2}",
                         this.Property1, this.Property2, this.Property3);
}
```

That's because `Console.WriteLine` will implicitly call the `ToString` method on a type that's not a `string`, and the default implementation of `ToString` simply returns the type's name.

---

This should work:

```
public class Response
{
     ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("ResponseID: {0}\nStatusID: {1}\nTitle: {2}\nProjectID: {3}\nSourceID: {4}\nSourceTitle: {5}\n...",
           ResponseID, StatusID, Title, ProjectID, SourceID, SourceTitle);
        // no need to call .ToString() on integer properties here, it's called implicitly anyway
    }
}
```

Output for `Console.WriteLine(Response);`

```
ResponseID: 1
StatusID: 123
Title: This is the title
ProjectID: 1
SourceID: 456
SourceTitle: This is the source title
```

In your `ToString` override you can specify exactly *how* you want each property to appear, for example `{0:C2}` would print `1` as `$1.00`. Also you might want to use `\t` (tab) to line up the output.

Comment: Well you'd only do that once, ToString tells the system how your class should render itself as a string. The alternative is to use Reflection which imho is a bit overkill.

Comment: Would dataGridView.DataSource= dc.GetTable<Response> work in this case? If yes, then how can I use it to print out the result?

Comment: You would use the exact same code you've posted in your question! :)

Comment: Actually `Console.Write(response);`