# C# printing LINQ-table to console without specifying the properties

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to make a method to print a LINQ (table) with all its properties and values to the console.

I'm currently trying to do this via the `System.Reflection.GetType().GetProperties()`
<strike>What I think is going wrong is the type of parameter I try to send to the method.</strike>
 If possible this should be a `var` so I can use this method with any class list. (not sure if this is possible)

The issue is with the `printtabel()` method.

I started from:
 [Print a table with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560974/print-a-table-with-linq)

```
namespace LINQ
{
class Program
{
    public class Bier
    {
        public int BierNr      { get; set; }
        public string Biernaam { get; set; }
        public float Alcohol   { get; set; }
        public Brouwer Brouwer { get; set; } //associatie met een brouwer 
        public override string ToString() { return Biernaam + ": " + Alcohol     + "% alcohol"; }
    }
    public class Brouwer
    {
        public int BrouwerNr      { get; set; }
        public string Brouwernaam { get; set; }
        public bool Belgisch      { get; set; }
        public List<Bier> Bieren  { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() { return "Brouwerij " + Brouwernaam + " (" + (Belgisch ? "Belgisch" : "Niet Belgisch") + ")"; }
    }
    public class Brouwers
    {
        public List<Brouwer> GetBrouwers()
        {
            List<Brouwer> lijst = new List<Brouwer>();
            Brouwer palm = new Brouwer { BrouwerNr = 1, Brouwernaam = "Palm", Belgisch = true };
            palm.Bieren = new List<Bier> {
                new Bier {BierNr=1,Biernaam="Palm Dobbel", Alcohol=6.2F, Brouwer=palm},
                new Bier {BierNr=2, Biernaam="Palm Green", Alcohol=0.1F, Brouwer=palm},
                new Bier {BierNr=3, Biernaam="Palm Royale", Alcohol=7.5F, Brouwer=palm}
            };
            lijst.Add(palm);
            Brouwer hertogJan = new Brouwer { BrouwerNr = 2, Brouwernaam = "Hertog Jan", Belgisch = false };
            hertogJan.Bieren = new List<Bier> {
                new Bier{ BierNr=4, Biernaam="Hertog Jan Dubbel", Alcohol=7.0F, Brouwer=hertogJan},
                new Bier{ BierNr=5, Biernaam="Hertog Jan Grand Prestige", Alcohol=10.0F, Brouwer=hertogJan} };
            lijst.Add(hertogJan);
            Brouwer inBev = new Brouwer { BrouwerNr = 3, Brouwernaam = "InBev", Belgisch = true };
            inBev.Bieren = new List<Bier> {
                new Bier { BierNr=6, Biernaam="Belle-vue kriek L.A", Alcohol=1.2F, Brouwer=inBev},
                new Bier { BierNr=7, Biernaam="Belle-vue kriek", Alcohol=5.2F, Brouwer=inBev},
                new Bier { BierNr=8, Biernaam="Leffe Radieuse", Alcohol=8.2F,Brouwer=inBev},
                new Bier { BierNr=9, Biernaam="Leffe Triple", Alcohol=8.5F,Brouwer=inBev} };
            lijst.Add(inBev);
            //return new List<Brouwer> { palm, hertogJan, inBev };
            return lijst;
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var brouwers = new Brouwers().GetBrouwers();
        var belgischeBrouwerijenMet3Bieren =
            from brouwer in brouwers
            where brouwer.Belgisch && brouwer.Bieren.Count == 3
            select brouwer;

        foreach (var brouwer in belgischeBrouwerijenMet3Bieren)
            Console.WriteLine(brouwer.Brouwernaam);

        var bieren = from brouwer in brouwers
                     from bier in brouwer.Bieren
                     select bier;


        string vorigeBrouwer = "";
        foreach (var bier in bieren)
        {
            if (bier.Brouwer.ToString() != vorigeBrouwer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bier.Brouwer);
                vorigeBrouwer = bier.Brouwer.ToString();
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"\t {bier.ToString()}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(printtabel(belgischeBrouwerijenMet3Bieren));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public string printtabel(IEnumerable<Brouwer> response)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in response.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            object value = prop.GetValue(response, new object[] { });
            sb.AppendLine($"{prop.Name} = {value}");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: _"What I think is going wrong is"_ - read [ask], don't guess, post the actual error and show what you found when you researched it.

Comment: That example does a flat object with just strings/primitive types , it wont know how to do a nested object of lists, you will have to inspect and adjust accordingly

Comment: what error you are geting or what is not working fine ?

Comment: Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.printtabel(IEnumerable<Program.Brouwer>)' LINQ  204 Active

Comment: @Hapkin what is the variable vorigeBrouwer?

Comment: @aloisdg vorigeBrouwer is a string 
oh I edited some new issues give me a few min plz :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.printtabel(IEnumerable)'    LINQ    204 Active

You can fix it by writing:

```
public static string printtabel(IEnumerable<Brouwer> response)
```

You are calling a non static method from a static method. Set `printtabel` static and this error should disappear.

Comment: ok thanks the error is indeed gone with adding the static

 I will go from there to finding the solution printing all the properties